# Reload Page without changing DOM - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that I am creating, and I am trying to add a link to the top that will add a css file. I think that it is not working because I load the page, then add the link element and it never actually puts the styles found in the css file to the elements. I tried having it reload the page using location.reload(), but that took the link element away from the page. Any suggestions on how to do this would be great. I would prefer not to use jquery, but I can if needed.

Current Code:

```
function findCss() {
    var fileref=document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", "styles/index.css")
}
```

window.onload = findCss;

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
document.body.appendChild(fileRef);
```

or

```
document.head.appendChild(fileRef);
```

at the end of that function, depending on where you want the link to be put (header or body).